# Equation of straight line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know,

$Ax + By = C$

is the equation of straight line but a different resource says that:

$y = mx + b$

is also an equation of straight line? Are they both same?

Comment: The first is called an _implicit_ equation, and the second a function. The values $A$, $B$, $C$ are sometimes called the coordinates for the line, and the values $m$, $b$ the parameters for the line.

Comment: There is an other line representation with $(x,y)=(x_1,y_1)+t\,(n_x,n_y)$ derived from a point $(x_1,y_1)$ and a direction $(n_x,n_y)$.

Comment: $Ax+By=C$ is sometimes called *general form*, *general linear form*, or *standard form*; $y=mx+b$ is often called *slope-intercept form*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That is, they both give the equation of a straight line and the equation of any non-vertical line can be written in either form.

If $B\ne 0$. Then you can write $Ax+By=C$ as
$$
By=-Ax+C 
$$
and, since  $B\ne0$, the above can be written
$$
y=-\textstyle{A\over B}x +{C\over B}.
$$

If $B=0$, the equation is $Ax=C$, which is a vertical line when $A\ne0$. In this case you can't write it in the form $y=mx+b$ (which defines a function).

On the other hand, given $y=mx+b$, you can rewrite it as $-mx+y=b$.

---

Note that for the equation $Ax+By=C$ with $A$ and $B$ both non-zero:

The $y$-intercept of its graph is $C/B$ and is found by taking $x=0$.

The $x$-intercept is of its graph is  $C/A$ and is found by taking $y=0$.

The slope of the line is then $ {C/B-0\over 0-C/A } = -A/B$.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

$Ax + By = C$

$By = -Ax + C$

$y = -(A/B)x + C/B$

Let $m = -\frac{A}{B}$.  Let $b = \frac{C}{B}$.

$y = mx + b$

So they are equivalent.

Comment: This was a good idea. It helps many people to illustrate equivalency in the most blunt way possible: Proving it.